# Intermittent save file problem over SFTP with CodeAnywhere

Tags: codeanywhere

I am having problems saving files when using CodeAnywhere with an FTPS connection. It will save a handful of times fine, other times it will just error after 30 seconds or so. Codeanywhere dont answer support emails or if they do they just say its fixed when its not.

Has anyone else had similar problems?

Ive tried disabling firewall to rule that out, with no avail.

[image: CodeAnywhere save file error modal]

[image: Chrome console error log]

Comment: Does this happen on several devices or only on your computer?

Comment: happens on multiple computers, all macs. happens on multiple browsers too.

Comment: Does this happen to only one specific SFTP connection? Because SFTP connections are working fine for me...

Comment: nope, happens with 2 different connections, different servers in different locations. its fine 95% of the time, seems to not save every 20 or so saves?

Comment: Ive tried a brand new install of centos 7.6 with cpanel installed with a vultr server all with default config and having the same problem trying to edit a simple text file over SFTP